# Why does free_reserved_area() take a char * instead of a const char *?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, compiler-warnings

```
unsigned long free_reserved_area(void *start, void *end, int poison, char *s)
```

The fourth argument causes tons of warnings in the code I'm working on:

```
warning: passing argument 4 of ‘free_reserved_area’
  discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
  [enabled by default]
```

`free_reserved_area()` is declared here:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/mm.h#L1861

and I see in its implementation the `char* s` is only read with `pr_info()`:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/page_alloc.c#L6625

Do you know why `free_reserved_area()` takes a `char *` rather than a `const char *` as fourth argument?

Comment: Who'd have thought it, Linus Torvalds can make a mistake. I think it's unlikley anybody here can answer that question without speculating. I'd guess one of two things: 1. this code was written at a time when they felt the need to support compilers too old to have `const`. 2. They simply forgot.

Comment: Linus is very aware of const correctness, see [here](http://yarchive.net/comp/const.html). But being the dictator that he is, he sometimes accepts patches from his capos without too much scrutiny, since he trusts them. If you feel this is an important patch, then you can always send a pull request.